# Why is template disambiguator needed in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, opencl

I'm trying to understand why I need to use a template disambiguator in some openCL code.

EDIT:  Here's a minimal reproducing case:

```
//test.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "cl.hpp"

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    public:
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;    
    Foo();   
    void bar();
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo() {      
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
}

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::bar() {
    // Fails to compile:  error: expected expression
    //std::cout << devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;
    // Works
    std::cout << devices[0].template getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;
    // Also works
    cl::Device &mydevice = devices[0];
    std::cout << mydevice.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

}
```

and the source file:

```
//test.cpp
#include "test.hpp"

int main() {
    Foo<double> foo = Foo<double>();    
    foo.bar();    
    return 0;
}
```

What is different about the reference that makes a template disambiguator unnecessary?  I"m trying to understand where the ambiguity is here. (Also, I know I'm not using the templated variable in my class, this is just a minimal case that reproduced the issue.)

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug if the keyword `template` is necessary outside the template code. Could you give us a bigger piece of the problem code?

Comment: If I have time I'll come up with a small reproducing case, but I can't post the code as is.  My compiler version is:


$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: Is that code inside a template (class/function)?

Comment: Yes a template class.  I just don't understand how getInfo gets confused for something else.

Comment: If you don't show the real code nobody else is going to understand it either.

Comment: [Here's an SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d34bd6fbc5ec816) that reproduces the problem on clang++3.5

Comment: @dyp There's no problem in the code in this question. It's a dup of the very frequently asked question. For some reason my close vote didn't auto-post a comment.

Comment: I think the answer is [temp.names]/4, which requires to insert that `template` because the postfix-expression expression in that function call is type-dependent (as `this` is type-dependent). I'm still trying to figure out why there's no exception for members of the current instantiation (the exception in [temp.names]/4 only applies to the qualified-id case as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Potatoswatter As I said in my previous comment, it's not quite clear to me (even after re-reading Johannes' answers) why the `template` is needed in *this* case, where we have a member of the current instantiation that is of a non-dependent type.

Comment: @dyp OK, didn't see that. I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: @dyp I think it is a bug in *clang*. *gcc* compiles this code fine (even with `-pedantic-errors` flag).

Comment: @Constructor Wow that's weird. Look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39d50d7fb1a038d7).

Comment: @dyp Interestingly. But both `devices[0].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()` and  `this->devices[0].cl::Device::getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()` compile with gcc (and none of them with clang).

Comment: Is this reproducible without using `opencl`? I am curious to try the code but don't want to deal with `opencl`.

Comment: I reduced the example [further here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9416e15654bfe3a) getting rid of lots of extraneous stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is just a typical issue in general in template code. The issue is that because, *at the point of parsing* the nature of `getInfo` is unknown (is it a function template or a regular member variable ?) the parser does not know whether to interpret `<` as less-than or as the start of specifying template parameters.

Thus the rule in **§14.2 [temp.names]/4**, of which the example is:

```
template<class T> void f(T* p) {
    T* p1 = p->alloc<200>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
    T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
    T::adjust<100>();                 // ill-formed: < means less than
    T::template adjust<100>();        // OK: < starts template argument list
}
```

Now, in your case this seems a bit silly I fathom, because it's a `Device` right ? Yes, *in your case*. But what of:

```
template <typename T> struct Wrecker { using type = std::vector<Device>; };
template <> struct Wrecker<double> { using type = std::vector<Other>; };

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    using Devices = typename Wrecker<T>::type;
    Devices devices;

    void bar();
};
```

So, yes, the rule is *not* as precise as it could be. It could delve even further into the fray and check whether the actual type can be deduced...

... but do you realize that, as it is, the simple fact of allowing you to elide `template` in some circumstances (non-dependent situations) already requires one of the worst compiler hacks ever ? The traditional pipeline: tokenization -> parsing -> semantic analysis has to be completely twisted in C++ to allow *feedback* of semantic analysis during the parsing phase to automatically disambiguate that `foo<4>()` is a template call.

Personally, my recommendation would have been to mandate `template` systematically. It would have saved a lot of troubles.